# .NET: Find hex strings with regular expressions

Tags: .net, regex

I need help with regular expression.

I have very large collection of text files with different contents. But every file contains one hexadecimal key. Every key has exactly 16 hexadecimal digits (`"E4 34 F1 FB..."`) and always begins with `"00"` or `"01"`. In some cases they have one separator character (`":"`).

Here are some example keys:

```
00:C461F0538ECC84F1AF43DBBDC49E5DA3
00:F4F599D15353650F1566CFEB5CB891C1
011EC3991261BFD8D74BBCFE1E3108628C
003E05F7730347E43437F1FBCAB3A8B461
018FAE7FFB2DBB64F646F705525DEB25F8
00)339EDE5269DD018C2FD5338AD18C3A2F
00B8491FDF00C618A155350F47349E7B04
```

How to extract these keys from strings with a regular expression in .NET (VB.NET or C#)?

Here are a couple of strings for testing:

```
KAJSDF00ASLJKHFLAKJSDHFLAK01JSH00:C461F0538ECC84F1AF43DBBDC49E5DA3DFLKJAHSDFJAVHBEVBERJHVBQEJHRVBQJERBV
JKLABDVJ01KBQLKJFBVQLEJKRBVL00:F4F599D15353650F1566CFEB5CB891C1QERBVJHQEBRVJHQBERFVHBQERVJHBQEJH
RVBQJHERVBJHQBRVJHQEBRVJHWEBRV011EC3991261BFD8D74BBCFE1E3108628CWKBERVJHWERFGUQHERULIFHQW
EIFH2FPO00I134FWFQWHEF34HFQREW018FAE7FFB2DBB64F646F705525DEB25F8F2347YQ3EFQO84R93U48UY8RTU13
R1R0100910R14UYR891UYFR1UEF98U1FPH00)339EDE5269DD018C2FD5338AD18C3A2F138294FH190324FU134UF19834YF
```

Comment: Second to last key looks like a typo at 3rd character.

Comment: Your example keys are too long....

Comment: This definitely needs clarification. How would you distinguish the start of a key from any other part of the file that happens to be "00" or "01"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
0[01][\:\(\)]?([0-9A-F]){16}
```

Don't have a regex parser to test this but that should search for a

- 0,
- followed by a 0 or 1,
- followed by the possible (but not compulsory) occurrence of a ':', '(' or ')'
- followed by 16 consecutive characters with possible values of (0123456789ABCDEF)

Comment: Why all the escaping backslashes in the character class? None of them is actually necessary. The parentheses around [0-9A-F] are not needed either. :)

Comment: This regex is over complicated and not optimised, important if the files are large. The only valid character after 00 or 01 is : so no need for the extra matches. You don't need the group around [0-9A-F]. This also does not match lower case hex. Each [0-9A-F character will be in it's own sub group.

Comment: @Tomalak is right, but nevertheless, a good answer. Though you should change the count of 16 to 32. Here's my version: "0[0|1][:()]?(?<Key>[A-F\d]{32})".

Comment: @Cerebrus: You don't need to use the pipe symbol in a character class (strictly speaking: its wrong to do so).

Answer (score 3):

The following regex will match your keys and be case insensitive

```
(?:00|01):?[a-fA-F0-9]{32}
```

This is assuming that the OP meant a 32 charachter string. If it is meant to be a 16 character string then change {32} to {16}.

Comment: You're right, so why didn't you change the 16 to 32 ? Another thing, I think all of us thought that the OP meant that brackets are valid separators. ;-) +1

Comment: @Cerebrus - Cheers. Changed to 32 character. The seperator wording wasn't overly clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
    string data = @"KAJSDF00ASLJKHFLAKJSDHFLAK01JSH00:C461F0538ECC84F1AF43DBBDC49E5DA3DFLKJAHSDFJAVHBEVBERJHVBQEJHRVBQJERBVJKLABDVJ01KBQLKJFBVQLEJKRBVL00:F4F599D15353650F1566CFEB5CB891C1QERBVJHQEBRVJHQBERFVHBQERVJHBQEJHRVBQJHERVBJHQBRVJHQEBRVJHWEBRV011EC3991261BFD8D74BBCFE1E3108628CWKBERVJHWERFGUQHERULIFHQWEIFH2FPO00I134FWFQWHEF34HFQREW018FAE7FFB2DBB64F646F705525DEB25F8F2347YQ3EFQO84R93U48UY8RTU13R1R0100910R14UYR891UYFR1UEF98U1FPH00)339EDE5269DD018C2FD5338AD18C3A2F138294F";
    for (Match match = Regex.Match(data, "0[01]:?[0-9A-F]{16}"); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch()) {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
```